# Convert from arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, arrow-functions

I will be very happy if you can help me.
I am making react native expo app. I have code that displays information from the database. But i want convert this code from arrow functions to normal function.

```html
<View>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}
          renderRow={(rowData) =>
            <Text
                      onPress={() => {
                        /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                          otherParam: rowData.article_title,
                        });
                      }}
                    >{rowData.article_title}</Text>
      }
        />
</View>
```

I want to have something like this, but i do not know how to do this:

```html
<View>
     <Text
       onPress={() => {
             /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
                 this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                    otherParam: rowData.article_title,
              });
          }}
        >{rowData.article_title}</Text>
      }
</View>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to convert from arrow function to normal function?

Comment: Even with the very weird code and that maybe something is missing, This isn't a duplicate

Comment: @Vencovsky i want to convert this code because when i add <Image/>, i am getting error

Comment: Please edit your question, add the correct code and the part where you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
onPress(() => { /* some code */})
```

Is equivalent to

```
function doOnPress() {
/* some code */
}

onPress(doOnPress.bind(this))
```

Comment: What about the use of `this`?

Comment: NO! It isn't. In particular the handling of `this` (which is used in the code in the question) is very different.

Comment: You should be able to use .bind(this)

Comment: No, am speaking about this code: renderRow={(rowData) => , not about onpress